# Removing the n-th element in a list

Tags: c++

To remove the i-th element of a list I am currently following the syntax below:

```
std::list<int> remaining{1,2,3,4,5};

auto it = remaining.begin();
advance(it, i);
remaining.erase(it);
```

Is there a less verbose way of achieving this? Similarly, for insert the following is the syntax I am following. Can it be less verbose as well?

```
it = remaining.begin();
advance(it, i);
remaining.insert(it, el);
```

Comment: What is the list? A [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?

Comment: `remaining` is a `std::list` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).  Your erase call would be

```
remaining.erase(std::next(remaining.begin(), i));
```

and your insert call would be

```
remaining.insert(std::next(remaining.begin(), i), el);
```